# C#: How do we try parse based on a condition?

Tags: c#, enums, tryparse

Am trying to try parse based on a condition between two enums, how do we do this?

```
bool _isEnum1 = true;

public enum _Enum1
{
value,
Text,
Image
}

public enum _Enum2
{
TextArea,
Button,
Label
}

var _enum = _isEnum1 ? Enum.TryParse("value", out _Enum1 _enum) : Enum.TryParse("TextArea", out _Enum2 _enum)
```

I want '_enum' to hold right enum type value. Is this possible? Any other alternative is also fine.

Comment: well it's kinda hard to decide which enum would come back from your statement, how come you don't know that at the time? Also, why are you parsing something which can apparently be hard coded?

Comment: That`s coming from a third enum, bool sets based on that, depending upon the enum type I want to continue further to execute some queries.

Comment: That sound needlessly complicated, you cannot rethink your program flow?

Comment: it`ll be little more complicated for me to change the flow, why do you think this sounds complicated?

Comment: @DeSon: Unwillingness to change the application to the new specifications is not a good approach. You're trying to build a rickety system just to avoid doing it the right way. Even if it works, it's going to bite you in the ass in the future. I strongly suggest reevaluating your intended solution because it is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: In order to resolve the XY problem: what is your goal? What will you do with the `_enum` value after it has been parsed? I do not see a valid use case (nor compiler allowance) for a method to take in a value from an arbitrary (runtime-decided) enum type.

Comment: @Flater: I will have to run some queries in switch cases. Looks like this all not needed, I will consider changing my flow as you suggested. This feels more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're trying to have the type being dynamically resolved at runtime. You either have to split your entire program flow

```
if(_isEnum1)
{
    Enum1 e = (Enum1)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enum1), "value");
    HandleEnum1(e);
}
else
{
    Enum2 e = (Enum2)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enum2), "value");
    HandleEnum2(e);
}
```

where `HandleEnumX` are strongly typed with `EnumX`, so that the compiler knows what's going on, or go completely crazy overboard and use `dynamic`

```
dynamic e;
if(_isEnum1)
{
    e = (Enum1)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enum1), s);
}
else
{
    e = (Enum2)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enum2), s);
}
// Now e is either Enum1 or Enum2, resolved at runtime.
```

However, this seems wildly overcomplicated and more of a thought experiment than real code you should be pushing to production. You should probably rethink your design of this part of the program. At the very least, you might want to wrap your enums in a class to allow a more flexible design.

As a side note - you're using `TryParse` but never testing the returned value, so I took the liberty of exchanging them to `Parse`.

Comment: Yes! I indeed go to change the code flow. Thanks for your reply. Love your logic too.

Answer (score -1):

```
Enum result;
if (this._isEnum1)
{
    result = (_Enum1)Enum.Parse(typeof(_Enum1), "value");

}
else
{
    result = (_Enum2)Enum.Parse(typeof(_Enum2), "TextArea");
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `TryParse` if you don't actually observe if the parsing succeeded?

Comment: @Backs: Though this looks like easy logic I might consider changing my flow itself. Thanks!